# Toast isn't working, can't see why not

Tags: java, android, spinner, if-statement

So I'm trying to write an activity that has two spinners and a button, when the two spinners are selected and the button pressed it'll take you to another activity. Except for one combination, which should produce a Toast saying that you can't do this.

Anyway, this is the code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

              String spinnerchoice1 = ("spinner1Value");
              String spinnerchoice2 = ("spinner2Value");

              if((spinnerchoice1.equals("Walking")) && (spinnerchoice2.equals("Hiking"))){

                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "I'm sorry, this is not possible.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }else{

                  Intent i = new Intent(GetDirections.this.getApplicationContext(), DirectionDisplay.class);
                  i.putExtra("spinner1Value", transportSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()); 
                  i.putExtra("spinner2Value", locationSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                  GetDirections.this.startActivity(i);

              }

          }
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure is entering that `if`? did you tried to put a log inside to test it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are comparing two hard-coded strings, the if condition will never execute. Change the code to:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  String transport = transportSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
  String location = locationSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

  if ("Walking".equals(transport) && "Hiking".equals(location)) {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "I'm sorry, this is not possible.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } else {
      Intent i = new Intent(GetDirections.this.getApplicationContext(), DirectionDisplay.class);
      i.putExtra("spinner1Value", transport); 
      i.putExtra("spinner2Value", location);
      GetDirections.this.startActivity(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is your actual code then your if is never going to evaluate to true because you are setting the strings to values that are not "Walking" and "Hiking"

these two lines:

```
String spinnerchoice1 = ("spinner1Value");
String spinnerchoice2 = ("spinner2Value");
```

need to be something like this (assuming that you spinner just contains String objects and not some other type):

```
String spinnerchoice1 = transportSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
String spinnerchoice2 = locationSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```